# How to make xdotool work with matchbow-window-manager?

Tags: linux, raspbian, xdotool, iceweasel

I have trouble using xdotool to simulate simple keypresses in my browser.

Now my browsers starts up on boot by adding the following code in '/home/pi/.xintirc'

```
#!/bin/sh
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank

// not sure if this is needed.
killall -TERM matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;
killall -9 matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

exec matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no &
iceweasel [someURL]
python /etc/xdo_test.py
```

My /etc/xdo_test.py looks as follows:

```
import time
import subprocess

time.sleep(20)
subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "c"]);
```

I don't have any output of this file while using it on startup but if I excecute this in another console, I get the following output:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

Does anyone have an idea why I get this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I eventually found [this](http://www.angsuesser.at/informatik/raspberry/) tutorial and used some ideas from it. I'll post the solutions for the people who may have a similar problem.

This is what i placed in the /home/pi/.xinitrc file:

```
#!/bin/sh
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank

// not sure if this is needed.
killall -TERM matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;
killall -9 matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

exec matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no &
iceweasel [someURL] &
sudo /etc/xdo_test.sh
```

I changed the python script to a shell script an inserted the following code:

```
sleep 20
$WIN=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Iceweasel|head -1)
xdotool key --window $WIN c

while:
do
    sleep 300
done
```

The while loop at the end is something I added because Xserver crashed from the moment it lost connection to the script. I'm still looking for a cleaner solution to end the script but this works for now. I'll update this awnser when I find one.

Thanks Sebastian Stigler for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You use in the python script the `subprocess.call` command. This call don't set the currently set environment variables in the subprocesse. Hence the missing display. Simply call the xdotool command in the `.xinitrc` file directly.

```
#!/bin/sh
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank

// not sure if this is needed.
killall -TERM matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;
killall -9 matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

exec matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no &
iceweasel [someURL] &           #<--- add ampersand
sleep 20
# you have to determine the window to which you want to send the keystroke
WIN=`xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class iceweasel | head -1`
# then activate it
xdotool windowactivate $WIN
# and send the keystroke
xdotool key --window $WIN c
```

If you have problems with the ampersand in the `iceweasel` call try to put quotes around the URL.

Comment: The browsers doesn't start when I use the ampersand :s.

This might be a stupid question but how do I set the DISPLAY environment variable with python?

Comment: Ok apparently I needed to add sudo before the python script, but I can still not run the browser. I get the following error: unable to open display "". Do I also have to specify the display in the .xinitrc file? How do I do that?

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your help! I got no Errors this time. Sadly xdotool doesn't seem to do anything. I'll try to set another, more complete testscenario. That might give me some clues.

Comment: After reading the manual for `xdotool`, it looks like you have to first determine the window-id, activate the window and then send the keystroke. See the edited answer for the implementation.

Comment: Ok I tried this. Now I get a an error saying: "search: unrecognized option '--sync'
Invalid use" . When I remove the '--sync', iceweasel crashes.
Output with '--sync':
http://prntscr.com/76ycbx
Output when sync removed:
http://prntscr.com/76ybpw

Answer (score 0):

call xdo_test.sh before running the window manager

Comment: Could you add some explanations around the answer?